# Action script error 1084 flex project 3.6

Tags: actionscript

I am getting an error of 1084 in flash builder project. I want to share the file which I am getting an error.

```
 package com.bykd.g4m.lobby.data
{
   import com.bykd.xcom.data.DataObject;
   import flash.utils.Dictionary;
   import com.bykd.xcom.data.Room;
   import com.bykd.xcom.data.User;
   import com.bykd.g4m.lobby.GameManager;

   public class GameInfo extends DataObject
   {

      public static const INIT_STATUS:Number = 1;

      public static const BET_OPTION:String = "BET";

      public static const EMPTY_STATUS:Number = 0;

      public static const STATUS_ELEMENT:String = "STATUS";

      public static const DRAW_OPTION:String = "DRAW";

      public static const WINROUNDS_OPTION:String = "WINROUNDS";

      public static const CREATE_STATUS:Number = 2;

      public static const GAME_ELEMENT:String = "GAME";

      public static const OPTIONS_ELEMENT:String = "OPTIONS";

      public static const OBJECT_ELEMENT:String = "GAMEINFO";

      public static const TIME_OPTION:String = "TIME";

      public static const CREATOR_ELEMENT:String = "CREATOR";

      public static const READY_STATUS:Number = 3;

      public static const SCORE_OPTION:String = "SCORE";

      public static const OPPONENT_ELEMENT:String = "OPPONENT";


      private var __id:uint;

      public var gameStatus:Number;

      public var gameOptions:Dictionary;

      public var gameRoom:Room;

      public var gameOpponent:User;

      public var gameCreator:User;

      public var gameJoined:Boolean;

      public function GameInfo(id:uint = 0, status:Number = 0, creator:User = null)
      {
         super();
         __id = id;
         gameStatus = status;
         gameCreator = creator;
         gameOptions = new Dictionary();
         gameJoined = false;
      }

      public static function parseHeader(xml:XML) : Object
      {
         var nodeName:String = xml.localName();
         var nodeParts:Array = nodeName.split("_",2);
         return {
            "element":nodeParts[0],
            "id":parseInt(nodeParts[1])
         };
      }

      override public function toXML() : XML
      {
         return new XML("<" + (OBJECT_ELEMENT + "_" + ID) + "/>");
      }

      override public function toXMLData(full:Boolean = true) : XML
      {
         var dataXML:XML = null;
         var key:* = null;
         var xml:XML = toXML();
         if(full)
         {
            if(!isNaN(gameStatus))
            {
               dataXML = new XML("<" + STATUS_ELEMENT + "/>");
               dataXML.appendChild(gameStatus.toString());
               xml.appendChild(dataXML);
            }
            if(gameCreator != null)
            {
               dataXML = new XML("<" + CREATOR_ELEMENT + "/>");
               dataXML.appendChild(gameCreator.toXML());
               xml.appendChild(dataXML);
            }
            if(gameOptions != null)
            {
               dataXML = new XML("<" + OPTIONS_ELEMENT + "/>");
               for(key in gameOptions)
               {
                  **dataXML.appendChild(new XML("<" + key + ">" + ({gameOptions[key]}) + "</" + key + ">"));**
               }
               xml.appendChild(dataXML);
            }
            if(gameOpponent != null)
            {
               dataXML = new XML("<" + OPPONENT_ELEMENT + "/>");
               dataXML.appendChild(gameOpponent.toXML());
               xml.appendChild(dataXML);
            }
            if(gameRoom != null)
            {
               dataXML = new XML("<" + GAME_ELEMENT + "/>");
               dataXML.appendChild(gameRoom.toXML());
               xml.appendChild(dataXML);
            }
         }
         return xml;
      }

      public function get ID() : uint
      {
         return __id;
      }

      override public function fromXML(xml:XML) : void
      {
         var dataXML:XML = null;
         var userXML:XML = null;
         var roomXML:XML = null;
         var gameManager:GameManager = null;
         var node:XML = null;
         var key:String = null;
         var header:Object = parseHeader(xml);
         if(header.element == OBJECT_ELEMENT)
         {
            __id = header.id;
            gameManager = GameManager.getInstance();
            dataXML = xml.elements(STATUS_ELEMENT)[0];
            if(dataXML != null)
            {
               gameStatus = Number(dataXML.toString());
            }
            dataXML = xml.elements(CREATOR_ELEMENT)[0];
            if(dataXML != null)
            {
               userXML = dataXML.elements(User.OBJECT_ELEMENT)[0];
               if(userXML != null && User.checkID(userXML))
               {
                  gameCreator = gameManager.userService.getUserEntity(User.parseID(userXML));
               }
            }
            dataXML = xml.elements(OPTIONS_ELEMENT)[0];
            if(dataXML != null)
            {
               gameOptions = new Dictionary();
               for each(node in dataXML.elements())
               {
                  key = node.localName();
                  gameOptions[key] = node.toString();
               }
            }
            dataXML = xml.elements(OPPONENT_ELEMENT)[0];
            if(dataXML != null && dataXML.hasOwnProperty(User.OBJECT_ELEMENT))
            {
               userXML = dataXML.elements(User.OBJECT_ELEMENT)[0];
               if(userXML != null && User.checkID(userXML))
               {
                  gameOpponent = gameManager.userService.getUserEntity(User.parseID(userXML));
               }
            }
            dataXML = xml.elements(GAME_ELEMENT)[0];
            if(dataXML != null && dataXML.hasOwnProperty(Room.OBJECT_ELEMENT))
            {
               roomXML = dataXML.elements(Room.OBJECT_ELEMENT)[0];
               if(roomXML != null && Room.checkID(roomXML))
               {
                  gameRoom = gameManager.roomService.getRoomEntity(Room.parseID(roomXML));
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is in this line according to the flash builder:

```
dataXML.appendChild(new XML("<" + key + ">" + ({gameOptions[key]}) + "</" + key + ">"));
```

the program says that multiple markers at this line. 
it is a syntax error . thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thought (untested) : try `"</\"` or even `"<\/"`... could be an unescape issue. Or even `+ String( ({gameOptions[key]}) ) +`... just try something / experiment / investigate while you wait for Answer... Did you research for what _"multiple markers"_ means in XML speak? The explanation will be your solution. Good luck.

Comment: Why is gameOptions[key] wrapped inside of an object {} ? An Object should be a key / value pair, i think that might be your problem. Try "+ gameOptions[key] +"